# Making Ubuntu Default OS

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

Yes, I know this question has been asked many times, but I've read through those Q&As and haven't figured it out.

I'm trying to have 12.04 boot up upon turning on the computer.  As of now, windows 8 boots up instead, and does NOT load the grub screen at any time. If I do go to the grub screen (by pressing esc, then f9, then choosing to boot the partition I have ubuntu on) the first (default) choice is 12.04.
Ubuntu is installed from a usb drive and on a separate partition from windows 8.  The only partitioning changes I made from the original (windows 8 came pre-installed) was to cut the biggest partition in half-one half for ubuntu, one for windows.
The HDD loads in EFI mode and ubuntu was installed in EFI mode.

Thanks, I hope I don't sound as clueless as I am.

--Secure boot was disabled when I installed ubuntu.  --Many of the questions I read earlier seemed to deal with the order of boot options on grub, which I didn't see as a relevant problem. Most of what I read was about grub and using the terminal, but from what I can gather, the problem might be how I installed ubuntu or something else not grub-related.

--Boot info: paste.ubuntu.com/5996699/

Comment: "I hope I don't sound as clueless as I am." Hilarious! You've got humor. I know I should not upvote for humor... but this one is too good.

Comment: During installation was the `secure boot` option disabled ? If not, then probably this is the problem here.

Comment: I don't remember, NikTh, but re-installing with secure boot disabled (is it a UEFI setting? or does it come up after booting the usb drive?) shouldn't be a problem as this is a new laptop.

Comment: @Chelate could you please edit your question and add those questions you read that might be relevant but you didn't understood?

Comment: Please indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )